# dictionary sort on average not working

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to sort on the value averages but it seems only to sort by name. My code is as follows. Please let me know if there is anything obvious I'm doing wrong. Cheers:

```
#printing averages highest to lowest
player_averages = {name: sum(scores) / len(scores) for name, scores in player_stats.items()}
print("---------------------------------------------------------")
print("Player averages")
print("---------------------------------------------------------")
for name in sorted(player_averages):
print("Sorted Average scores--------->>> ", name, player_averages[name]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default it will sort on keys. You should use the key argument to define your sort. For example:

```
>>> sorted({1: 'D', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'E', 5: 'A'}.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])

[(5, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'B'), (1, 'D'), (4, 'E')]
>>>
```

`.items()` gives you an array of tuples (key, values of your dictionary elements). Then in your `lambda` you return `x[1]` which will be the value, e.g. `D` in `(1,'D')`.

In your case do:

```
sorted(player_averages.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: cheers. Thanks that works much appreciated. Please can you direct me to resources that will allow me to learn more about working with lists, dictionaries with all the adding and sorting that can be done. I find odd bits but nothing comprehensive to learn from. Cheers.